# Remainder of Taylor approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider the ODE $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with $f(x)$ smooth and let $x_0$ be an equilibrium, i.e. $x(t)=x_0=\text{const}$ and $f(x_0)=0$.

The substitution $x=x_0+y$ shifts the origin to $x_0$. With the new variables, the system may be written as
$$
\dot{y}=f(x_0+y)
$$
or, by Taylor expansion near $x=x_0$, as
$$
\dot{y}=f(x_0)+\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x}y+o(y).
$$
Since $f(x_0)=0$ this becomes
$$
\dot{y}=Ay+g(y),
$$
where $A=\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x}$. $A$ is a constant $(n\times n)$-matrix and $g(y)$ satisfies the condition
$$
g(0)=\frac{\partial g(0)}{\partial y}=0. (*)
$$

*Questions*

(1.) Why does $x=x_0+y$ shift the origin to $x_0$?

(2.) Why does $(*)$ hold? As far as I see,
$$
g(y):=f(x_0+y)-Ay,
$$
so, surely, $g(0)=f(x_0)=0$. But why $\frac{\partial g(0)}{\partial y}=0$?

Comment: 1. Most helpful thing to do is draw a picture.

2. $g(y)$ corresponds to your higher order _non-linear_ terms in $y$ (**quadratic or more**); Clearly the first partial derivative $\partial_{y} g$ exists and each term still contains the variable $y$. Thus, evaluating at $y=0$ causes each term to be zero, hence your result at $(*)$.

Comment: Concerning (2.), I do not see the point, sorry.

Comment: Write out the Taylor expansion for a few terms then, not using little o notation. Set $g(y)$ to be everything in the Taylor expansion that is quadratic or more in $y$. Take the partial derivative of $g(y)$. Evaluate the partial derivative of $g(y)$ at $y=0$. Look at what happens to each term.

Comment: Okay, this is the direct way. The tutor said it follows by $g(y):=f(x_0+y)-Ay$.

Comment: The $g(y)$ you have been given comes from the fact that $\dot y = f(x_{0}+y)$ and $\dot y = Ay + g(y)$, hence $f(x_{0}+y) = Ay + g(y) \implies g(y) = f(x_{0}+y) - Ay$. Take the partial derivative of the $g(y)$ you've been given and evaluate it at $y=0$ and see what happens.

Comment: I have some trouble computing the partial derivative of $g(y)$,

Comment: So do what I suggested in my second comment then.

Comment: By the way: Why can we make $x=x_0+y$? Doesnt this change the system and, f.e., its equilibria?